# drupal 7 services 3.0 create node with image

Tags: javascript, drupal-7

I'm really stuck with this; I'm uploading an image file and getting the fid but the subsequent request to create a node and attach the fid fails. The node is create although the image field is not filled in with the image fid and the image is not attached to the node.

I use this ajax to post the node:

```
$.ajax({
    url: localStorage.appurl+"/api/node.json",
    type: 'post',
   data: "node[title]=new node&node[type]=ftritem&node[field_ftritem_images][und][0]    [fid]=7895",
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': localStorage.usertoken
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log('error '+errorThrown);

    },
    success: function (data) {         
    console.log("Node created");

    }
  });
```

Im getting this error:

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in image_field_widget_form() (line 358 of /var/www/dt11/modules/image/image.field.inc).

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in file_field_widget_form() (line 526 of /var/www/dt11/modules/file/file.field.inc).

Has anyone faced this before ? Any suggestions are highly appreaciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in Drupal core. I made an issue for it here and a patch has been supplied, but it didn't work properly for me: https://www.drupal.org/node/1912458

I did get it to work by only doing part of what the patch does.

Find line 504 of modules/file/file.field.inc and change it from this:

```
if (($field['cardinality'] == FIELD_CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED || $delta < $field['cardinality']) && empty($form_state['programmed'])) {
```

To this:

```
if (($field['cardinality'] == FIELD_CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED || $delta < $field['cardinality'])) {
```

I don't know if this produces adverse side effects anywhere else, but it does allow services to be used in the way you are using it.

Comment: After applying the patch you have linked to, I had to change my workflow;  starting with posting the node then all the images and lastly I updated the node adding each image one by one. This works but  is not the most efficient method.

Comment: I agree that it's not a good solution and the issue definitely needs attention. Attaching files using services is surely not an uncommon requirement.